How can I add a "std=c99" flag to cc when compiling using cargo?
I'm trying to install ripgrep (link to repo) with the pcre2 feature from source.
To do so I run the command cargo build --release --feature 'pcre2' to build the exec.
When doing so, cargo tries to build some C files and throws a error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode as well as note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code and stops.
The command it launches is cc -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -gdwarf-4 [more args...] -o <path-to>-pcre2_script_run.o -c upstream/src/pcre2_script_run.c.
I've tried to alias cc to some different compilers but it does not have an effect. How can I specify a flag to cc (std=c99 in this case) so I can compile this project ?

Are you able to build a fresh project with pcre2-sys as dependency, or do you get the same error?

Doing cargo new foo ; cd foo ; cargo add pcre2-sys ; cargo build triggers the same error.

What OS are you using? What is your version of gcc/clang?

I use CentOS 7, as a non root user. There are countless versions of gcc and clang on it, including recent ones, to be honest I don't know which one cargo is aliasing as cc. I tried re-aliasing cc but it has no effect unfortunately.

pcre2-sys (which ripgrep depends on) fails to compile on CentOS indeed.
A fix proposed in the issue is to use export CC=c99, since the cc crate (which pcre2-sys uses to compile PCRE) uses that environment variable, if defined, to select the C compiler.

It did not function with CC=c99 because then there was another issue (option -gwarf-4 not recognized) but it did put me on the right track (I was aliasing instead of setting an env variable). My CC was set to gcc.
Using CC=clang cargo build ... worked, I could build ripgrep with the desired feature, thanks a lot. Maybe edit your message for others who would seek the right answer. Using clang version 17.0.6.
